# center categories in nav menu

Tags: css, navigation

I'm trying to center the text in my nav bar (categories).

I've tried text-align and various other options but nothing seems to be working.

My site is www.lifemaxuk.co.uk

Can someone have a look and please help as this is driving me mad!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu

Comment: Do you want to remove the second line or what is the purpose?

Comment: I want to center all the text so that the two categories on the second line are in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The a-element is already centered in the li-element.
So if you want to center the text in your blue nav you should change the css like this:

```
ul {
text-align:center;
}

li a,
li {
float:none;
display:inline;
text-align:center;
}
```